# Как обратиться к элементу строки @mui/datagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, mui

Я пытаюсь засунуть в табличные значения распаренные данные JSON. Проблема заключается в том, что время от времени необходимо, чтобы пользователь изменял данные в конкретной ячейке. Не могу понять как получить эти данные.
Имеется следующий код

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'number', headerName: 'Number', width: 150 },
    {
        field: "action",
        headerName: "Print Number",
        sortable: false,
        renderCell: (params) => {
          const onClick = (e) => {
            //Problem are here
            console.log(params.number) // This is not working 
          };
    
          return <Button onClick={onClick}>Print Number</Button>;
        }
        , width: 300
    }


const Table_Data = () => {



    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

    let link_to_fetch = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/get_table_data`
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(link_to_fetch)
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((data) => setTableData(data))
  
    }, [])
  
    console.log(tableData)
  
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 700, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={tableData}
          columns={columns}
            pageSizeOptions={[12,25,50,100]}
            getRowId={(row:GridRowProps) => row.number}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Как вывести в консоль number из той же строки, в которой был произведен клик? Похоже что я очень сильно туплю, но решение никак не могу найти

Comment: как я понимаю нужно просто использовать эвенты `cellEditStart` and `cellEditStop` как в [документации](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#events)

Comment: Если верить документации - необходимые данные должны храниться в params.props.value. Однако этот параметр остается неопределен

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался. Достаточно было внести columns внутрь основной константы.
Обращения к элементам ячейки идут как params.row.<field_name>